# what is the query to check whether data is present in Sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I parsed the json data  and put these values in database(Sqlite database). Next time when i open the activity it again parsed the data and put these values in database. 
        so i want to check first whether data is in sqlite?, if so then i need to skip parsing. And just get these values from database. how can i do this?

Comment: Simple **SELECT** Query which returns Cursor with data is enough for this.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361722/android-sqlite-query-detect-when-an-element-doesnt-exists-in-the-table/11361804#11361804

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Try to check if you can read data from SQLite: SELECT * FROM YourTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public int isDataAvailable()
    {
        int total = 0;
        try
        {
            Cursor c = null;
            c = db.rawQuery("select id from mycoupon", null);

            if(c.getCount() != 0)
                total = c.getCount();

            c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total; 
    }
```

**If there are no records in table then it returns 0 otherwise returns no of records.**

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 Always Welcome